# woocommerce - update shipping rate based on address field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I own a restaurant for which I'm developing a website for ordering food online. I'm using woocommerce for the website.

Since we'd be able to deliver only to limited areas within the city, I've customized the address line 2 to be a dropdown full of areas deliverable by us.

This much I've already done.

Now what I need is, to update the shipping cost based on the area selected from the dropdown.

I'm very new to wordpress AND php, so elaborately explained answers are appreciated.

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

I did some research and found a way to update the shipping price

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_flat_rate_shipping_add_rate','add_another_custom_flat_rate', 10, 2 );

function add_another_custom_flat_rate( $method, $rate ) {
$new_rate          = $rate;
$new_rate['cost']  = 50; // Update the cost to 50
$method->add_rate( $new_rate );
}
```

but I'm still stuck at how to get the area name within this function, I tried using `$fields['billing']['billing_address_2']` to refer it but that doesn't work.

It'd really be helpful if someone can help me get the address line 2 in that function.

TIA

**Edit 2:**
I've modified a code from the answer to my need, for now, I'm not using DB to get dropdown value, but just hardcoding them. And since this is wordpress, the fields are already existing, and I can work with them only. below is the slightly modified jQuery I'm using, I've saved it in my child theme as updateshipping.js:

```
<script>
$("#billing_address_2").change(function () {
/* ajax function */
var area =  $("#billing_address_2").val();

$.ajax({
    url: 'functions.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: { field1: area} ,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response.status);
        $("#order_review").val(response);
    },

}); 
}
</script>
```

`billing_address_2` is the `<select>` id

`order_review` is the div id I need to refresh

I'm also en-queuing the js in functions.php as given below:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'update_shipping' );

function update_shipping() {

wp_register_script( 'updateshipping', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/updateshipping.js',array('jquery') );
wp_enqueue_script( 'updateshipping' );

 }
```

For now, I've added this line in the add_another_custom_flat_rate function given above:

```
$area = $_REQUEST['area'];
echo $area;
```

but for some reason, the area is not getting fetched. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Please help, 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Might be possible using the built in [shipping zones](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-shipping-zones/)

Comment: Problem is, built in shipping zones use only pin code which is not that helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

you could use ajax/javascript, to resolve your problem,

1. create your php file,

```html
<select id = "address_cmbo" value =''>
 <option>query out the values from your database </option>
</select>

<input type="text" value = "" id="cost_textbox" >
```

2. create a function using javascript/jquery,

```html
   $("#address_cmbo").change(function () {
            
    /* ajax function */
    
    var address =  $("#address_cmbo").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'functions.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { field1: address} ,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.status);
            $("#cost_textbox").val(response);
        },

    }); 
   }
```

```html
 $address_value =   $_REQUEST['address'];
 $query = "Select cost from tbl_address ";
 $result = mysql_query($query);

 while( -> mysql_fetch_array){ 
---  display the actual cost from the result
 $cost =  $rows['cost'];
}
```

4. the value of your textbox will now change depending on the selected address.

Comment: Hi there, Thank you for the help, but I'm still not getting the output, I'm probably doing something wrong, I've made an edit to the question with the progress. Please help if you can, Thanks